# Scrollable TabBar cuts off first item on initial launch

Tags: flutter

I have a scrollable TabBar, and when in debug mode it works as expected. Once I create a build to my Android device, the scroll position of the TabBar starts out scrolled a little, cutting the first tab in half. You can scroll back manually, and switching tabs automatically scrolls it back to the correct position. This only happens when the app is initially launched.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eh3Je.jpg

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(TabBarDemo());
}

class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 9,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              isScrollable: true,
              tabs: [
                Tab(text: 'Test Tab 1'),
                Tab(text: 'Test Tab 2'),
                Tab(text: 'Test Tab 3'),
                Tab(text: 'Test Tab 4'),
                Tab(text: 'Test Tab 5'),
                Tab(text: 'Test Tab 6'),
                Tab(text: 'Test Tab 7'),
                Tab(text: 'Test Tab 8'),
                Tab(text: 'Test Tab 9')
              ],
            ),
            title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.directions_car),
              Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
              Icon(Icons.directions_car),
              Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
              Icon(Icons.directions_car),
              Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```